# Why variables are not working when declared outside the function?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am learning Javascript and have this code that I have been written in two ways, but I don't understand why it doesn't work when the variables 'r', 'g' and 'b' are outside the function scope. I already made my research and I've found a lot of answers but none of them is really objective.

The goal of this function (it is just for practice) is set aleatory colors to a square every 2 seconds. When I put the variables outside the function it is called just one time, but when they are inside the function it works properly.

Why these variables work only inside the function and the 'div' variable works either inside or outside?

*This Works:

```
var div = document.getElementById("dv1");

function changeColor() {
    var r = Math.floor(Math.random() * 255);
    var g = Math.floor(Math.random() * 255);
    var b = Math.floor(Math.random() * 255);
    div.style.backgroundColor = "rgb(" + r + "," + g + "," + b + ")";
}

setInterval(changeColor, 2000);
```

*This is not working:

```
var div = document.getElementById("dv1");
var r = Math.floor(Math.random() * 255);
var g = Math.floor(Math.random() * 255);
var b = Math.floor(Math.random() * 255);

function changeColor() {
   div.style.backgroundColor = "rgb(" + r + "," + g + "," + b + ")";
}

setInterval(changeColor, 2000);
```

Comment: Can you post the *non*-working code, so we can see what you're doing?

Comment: Hello. This is all I have. As I said, I am learning and it is just for practicing, I am not really building anything.

Comment: Your question mentions two situations, one of which works properly (which you posted), but one of which doesn't. If you want debugging help on why the other situation doesn't work properly, you'll have to post the non-working code

Comment: When the variables are outside the function they only get 1 value and they stay the same. When they are inside the function they get new values every time the function is called.

Comment: Sorry, I edited the code. The only difference between them is that the one with the varibles inside the function works and when the variables are outside it doesn't go well.

Comment: @takendarkk, so, when they are outside, the Math.random method is set just one time?

Comment: Yes. Then every time the function is called you are just setting the same r, g, b over and over.

Comment: @takendarkk Thank you very much. It makes sense now.

Comment: @chrispbacon p bacon Sorry, man. But I am a beginner and I am learning. Mystakes happen and they are allowed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has nothing to do with scope.

`var r = Math.floor(Math.random() * 255);` generates a random number and assigns it to `r`.

Every time you read `r`, you get that random number. The same random number.

You don't get a *new* random number unless you call `r = Math.floor(Math.random() * 255);` again.

Since you aren't calling `r = Math.floor(Math.random() * 255);` inside the function that you call on an interval, every time the interval comes round you assign the **same** set of values to `backgroundColor`.

Assigning a value to `div` and reusing it each time you go around the interval works because you **want the same div**.

You can declare the variables outside the function and it will work. You just need to assign the values inside the function.

```js
var div = document.getElementById("dv1");
var r, g, b;

function changeColor() {
  r = Math.floor(Math.random() * 255);
  g = Math.floor(Math.random() * 255);
  b = Math.floor(Math.random() * 255);
  div.style.backgroundColor = "rgb(" + r + "," + g + "," + b + ")";
}

function logColor() {
  console.log({
    r,
    g,
    b
  });
}

setInterval(changeColor, 2000);
setInterval(logColor, 1000);
```

```html
<div id="dv1">dv1</div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much. It was really enlightening. My mystake was thinking that just setting the variables in this line - div.style.backgroundColor = "rgb(" + r + "," + g + "," + b + ")"; - would make them be called.